# Laravel on Cloudways - Installed phpMyAdmin but Getting 404 Error

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, cloudways

I installed phpMyAdmin as per [Cloudways Instructions](https://support.cloudways.com/en/articles/5124779-how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-cloudways).

When I try to load /phpmyadmin I'm getting a Laravel generated 404 error - which is understandable because /phpmyadmin is not a defined route.  So, what's the fix?

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin is different host program.You can't access it via Laravel Setup due it's not hosts within same host setup.Laravel & PhpMyAdmins Are individual setups.

NOte: You need to create a subdomain of your main host using Virtual Host  point to your phpmyadmin setup.